# Send parameter to a BroadcastReceiver and check it in onReceive method

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I'm trying to send a bulk of sms messages in a loop, and for each message I need to register a braodcaseReceiver, to detect sent or received status.

I need to send the value of message id to the broadcastReceiver in order to be able mark that message as sent.

How can I pass the value of "id" to inside the BroadcastReceiver?

The code is as follows:

```
...
// message id will be different for each time a message is sent
String id = "101"; 

String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SENT);
Intent deliveredIntent = new Intent(DELIVERED);

PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, sentIntent, 0);
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, deliveredIntent, 0);

mContext.registerReceiver(
    new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent)
        {
            //I need to check the id of the message here 
            switch(getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    //updateSmsSentStatus(id);
                    break;
                ...
             }
             unregisterReceiver(this);
         }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, scAddress, smsMessage, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

**Note:**

To add more context to the problem:

- The code above is inside AsyncTask class. That task is being called several times to send multiple messages asynchronously.
- I tried sending the message id as extra to sentIntent and receive it inside onReceive (similar to Girish's answer), but I actually received only one value repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the `Intent` object, you can store Id in the `Intent` as follows,

```
Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SENT);
// assuming id is of type int
intent.putExtra("Id", id);
```

then in the `onReceive` method,

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent)
{
  int id = intent.getIntExtra("Id", -1); 
  // above -1 default value is returned if "Id" doesn't exist.

  //I need to check the id of the message here 
  switch(getResultCode())
    {
      case Activity.RESULT_OK:
        //updateSmsSentStatus(id);
        break;
        ...
     }
     unregisterReceiver(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. I run the code inside a loop for multiple messages, and when I putExtra to sentIntent, I get the wrong value when getIntExtra inside onReceive. Actually if I iterate three times with different ids, I keep getting one value for each call of onReceive instead of three different values.

Comment: How are you iterating? Can you share the whole code?